# How to pass form data to a simple Python Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and I am still learning the basics. I have a simple html form with a text input field which passes the data to a simple flask app. However, I am unable to get the dev server running. Usually for simple Hello World programs, I put all my Python and Flask code in a .py file and then run it as `python3 hello_world.py`. This automatically starts the Flask development server.

How can I get my simple html form to work? the code is shared below:

**login.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/login" method = "post">
         <p>Enter Name:</p>
         <p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**http.py**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
   return 'welcome %s' % name

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user = request.form['nm']
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))
   else:
      user = request.args.get('nm')
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

When I launch the html file and submit the form, it says that the site can't be reached, which is logical because the Flask dev server is not up yet. if I try `python3 http.py`, I get the following error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
  File "/home/neo/flask_projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/neo/flask_projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "/home/neo/flask_projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 61, in <module>
    import SocketServer as socketserver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SocketServer'
```

I know this is a very silly question but I would really appreciate some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name from `http.py` to something else. There is an `http` module in python and your file might be clashing with it.

And after you do that, you still have to return the `login.html` form as @miquelvir says.

Answer (score 1):

You are never returning the `login.html` template. If the request is a GET, then you must return the page; if it is a POST, then it's the form.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: However, I have a question. I renamed the file from http.py to http_test.py and the application worked. I opened the login.html file and it showed me the success page with the username with both post and get methods. The code works even if I do not use the render_template function. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: What do you mean by "I opened the login.html file"? How did you? The code without the return render_template should not work properly.